# How do I format dates appended from csv to xlsx using Openpyxl in Python?

Tags: python, date, format, openpyxl, xlsx

I'm using the following code to copy date values from a csv converted to xlsx, but the dates are appending as general. Even manual format painting doesn't seem to correct the issue. Is there something I'm missing in my format copy?

```
for col in range(1, mc2+1):
for row in range(3, mr2+1):
    source = ws2.cell(column=col, row=row-1)
    cell = ws2.cell(column=col, row=row)
    cell.font = copy(source.font)
    cell.border = copy(source.border)
    cell.number_format = copy(source.number_format)
    cell.alignment = copy(source.alignment)
    cell.fill = copy(source.fill)
```

11/1/2023 is what I'm seeing "left justified general number format"

I know csv files don't have a date format, but excel isn't translating it from general input as it would if I were typing it manually into the cell.

Coding a force to datetime "%m%d%Y" but I get the same general format after the append is complete.
Other date forces provide similar results.

I'm looking for short date format.
Range references are correct and account for differing header spaces between source and target sheets.

Comment: Please include code and examples as text not linked images.

Comment: f you have '11/1/2023' (without quotes) in a CSV file Excel would import it as a date. If you did force it to be a string in Excel Openpyxl will read it as a string so given your code sample it will be copied as a string, though there does not appear to be any line in the code sample that actually copies the cell value. If you want to convert from string to date then use datetime.strptime I.e. if you had a line to copy the source value then `cell.value = datetime.strptime(source.value, '%m/%d/%Y')` and set the Cell number_format as required.

Comment: Given your code sample copies say cell A2 to A3 then A3 to A4, A4 to A5 etc which seems a little redundant if all the cells are to be the same then why keep changing the source? Anyway once you have converted the string date to datetime date you can just copy the cell value as 'strptime' will give an error on the 2nd iteration since cell A3 will be datetime now so you dont need to convert it on that and subsequent loops.

Comment: "why keep changing the source?" - moken

I took the snippet from other code I'd written to take the previous cell's formatting. I see the redundancy here, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want but based on your code sample the following code sample might be useful.

This code will

1. Iterate the sheet by columns since you are copying the same value/formatting down the column for each cell.
2. Set the source as the first cell in the column starting at row 2 e.g. 'A2'.
3. Update the cells value/formatting to same as row 2 cell.

This code sample first changes the value in the row 2 cell to datetime if it is a string so copying that cell will have the correct number formatting.

```
from copy import copy
from datetime import datetime
from openpyxl import load_workbook


src_file = 'foo.xlsx'

wb2 = load_workbook(src_file)
ws2 = wb2['Sheet1']

mr2 = 6  # Some arbitrary row to stop at

### Start loop at row 2, row with the dates as string.
for row in ws2.iter_cols(min_row=2, max_row=mr2, max_col=ws2.max_column):
    source = row[0]  # Set source to first cell, e.g. 'A2'
    date_value = source.value  #  Get the cell value 
    if isinstance(date_value, str):  # Check if the value is a string 
        date_value = datetime.strptime(source.value, '%m/%d/%Y')  # If string convert to datetime.  

    ### Iterate the remaining cells in the column e.g. A3 to A{mr2} and update the value to the source value and formatting
    ### Set the number_format to Excel 'm/d/yyyy'
    for cell in row:
        cell.value = date_value
        cell.font = copy(source.font)
        cell.border = copy(source.border)
        cell.number_format = 'm/d/yyyy'
        cell.alignment = copy(source.alignment)
        cell.fill = copy(source.fill)

wb2.save('foo.xlsx')
```

Example output
For the example sheet with dates as string in row 2
[image: For the example source sheet]

Updated sheet. All date values including those on row 2 are now Excel dates and formatted as Excel 'm/d/yyyy'
[image: Updated sheet]